# Are there any ways to re-use subquery in SELECT FROM (query) syntax in JOIN part?

Tags: mysql

I have simple `test` table

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO test (id) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (6), (8), (9), (12);
```

And I'm trying to use subselect to add row numbers for each row (can't use ROW_NUMBER() or other hacks because of mysql version).

```
SELECT 
  tlist.id as `from`,
  tlist1.id as `to`
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      t1.id as id, @row_num := IFNULL(@row_num+1, 1) as num 
    FROM test as t1
  ) as tlist
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT 
      test.id as id, @row_num1 := IFNULL(@row_num1+1, 1) as num 
    FROM test
  ) as tlist1 ON tlist.num + 1 = tlist1.num
WHERE tlist.id + 1 < tlist1.id
```

The problem is that I forced to create new subselect for each row in `INNER JOIN` query because I can't do `INNER JOIN tlist as tlist1` since tlist isn't real database table. Are there any ways to re-use tslit subquery?

Comment: in MySQL 8.0 there is a way to re-use (sub)queries it's called CTS  (Common Table Expression) .(but MySQL 8.0 isn't production ready). in the lower MySQL versions there isn't anny way to reuse the (sub)queries

Comment: Thank you, CTE is an interesting syntax, will be waiting for 8.0, but currently trying to find the solution in mysql 5.6

Comment: What would the desired result look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Are there any ways to re-use tslit subquery* - No this is a way to simulate row_number functionality in mysql although the ifnull bit is more often expressed as a cross join like this -

```
SELECT 
  tlist.id as `from`,
  tlist1.id as `to`
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      t.id as id, @row_num := @row_num+1 as num 
    FROM t  cross join (select @row_num:=0) r
  ) as tlist
INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT 
      t.id as id, @row_num1 := @row_num1+1 as num 
    FROM t cross join(select @row_num1:=0) r1
  ) as tlist1 ON tlist.num + 1 = tlist1.num
WHERE tlist.id + 1 < tlist1.id;
```

But in this case

```
SELECT T1.ID T1ID ,(SELECT MIN(T2.ID) FROM T T2 WHERE T2.ID > T1.ID) T2ID
FROM T T1
HAVING  T1.ID + 1 < T2ID;
```

might suffice.
But I guess what you are really trying to establish is if there are any gaps in the id (assuming id increments by 1)?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I'm trying to find skips in ids sequence.